# Select last row and place it on the top

Tags: r

I have a data frame and I'd like to reorder it. I'd like to make the last row the top row.

Example, if I type `mtcars` into the console the last car listed is a volvo 142E. Suppose I wanted to make this the first row, how would I do that?

dplyr/tidyverse or base r preferred.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In base R -

```
mtcars[c(nrow(mtcars), seq(nrow(mtcars)-1)), ]

# top 6 rows
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Volvo 142E        21.4   4  121 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
```

---

Here's a generalized function for moving any row to top -

```
move_to_top <- function(df, n) {
  df[c(n, setdiff(1:nrow(df), n)), ]
}

head(move_to_top(mtcars, 32))

                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Volvo 142E        21.4   4  121 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a base R method which also works for rows other than the last row

```
to_top <- nrow(mtcars)
mtcars[order(seq(nrow(mtcars)) != to_top),]
#                      mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Volvo 142E          21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
# Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
# Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
# ...


to_top <- which(rownames(mtcars) == 'Valiant')
mtcars[order(seq(nrow(mtcars)) != to_top),]
#                      mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Valiant             18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
# Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
# Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
# Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
# Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
# Merc 240D           24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
# ...
```

You can also use `setdiff` for the same result

```
mtcars[c(to_top, setdiff(seq(nrow(mtcars)), to_top)),]
```

Or the `order` method in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% 
  rownames_to_column() %>% 
  arrange(row_number() != n())

#                rowname  mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# 1           Volvo 142E 21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
# 2            Mazda RX4 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# 3        Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# 4           Datsun 710 22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
# 5       Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
# 6    Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
# ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Another idea is to subset and bind rowwise, i.e.

```
rbind(tail(mtcars, 1), head(mtcars, -1))
#                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#Volvo 142E          21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
#Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#Valiant             18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
#Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
#Merc 240D           24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
#Merc 230            22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
#...
```

Comment: Simple question. How do you put `#` in front of all the outputs? I am sure you don't do this by hand. I post answers always without `#` .

Comment: Actually by hand. You can do it really fast...like 'hashtag/down arrow/left arrow' repeat :D

Comment: Oh my God! What a patience! I am starting to finger exercises :))

Comment: @maydin or you could copy/paste the result into the script window of RStudio and use ctrl+shift+c to comment everything. Or, hold down alt and select first character of all rows and enter a hash (see alt+ mouse drag [here](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/rstudio-IDE-cheatsheet.pdf)).

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Thank you very much. *ctrl+shift+c* is very useful. However, I wish there is a way in R Gui since I really hate using R Studio.

Comment: @maydin using RStudio (or Notepad, or any good text editor) we can hold ALT then use mouse to expand the cursor to multiple lines then type "#", done.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `slice`

```
library(tidyverse)    
mtcars%>%
      rownames_to_column('rn') %>%
      slice(c(n(),  1:(n()-1))) %>%
      column_to_rownames('rn')
#                 mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb NA_1 NA_2
#Volvo 142E          21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2   NA 21.4
#Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4   NA 21.0
#Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4   NA 21.0
#Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1   NA 22.8
#Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1   NA 21.4
# ...
```